# Adding additional information to progressbar for Wix bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

I have a wix bootstrapper application (currently using wix 3.9) that installs multiple msi packages that are downloaded from urls.  When the application starts the progress bar executes but doesn't provide any textual information that packages are currently downloading. I've been trying to search for ways to do this but haven't found any information.

Is there a way to add custom information regarding the msi download (eg. which package is currently downloading, estimated time ..etc) to the installation progress bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Was spent to match time looking for progress bar percentage text.
I think you need to add costume action to achieve that something like this :

https://taocoyote.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/adding-managed-custom-actions-to-the-progressbar/

also if you need info about what is installing you can use :

```
 <Text Name="OverallProgressPackageText" X="225" Y="291" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OverallProgressPackageText)</Text>
  <Text Name="ExecuteProgressActionDataText" X="11" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes" />
```

Theme file link

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_customize.html

another useful link :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331368/WIXDataBase

[How do I customise the Wix Progress Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422717/how-do-i-customise-the-wix-progress-dialog)